# Is it possible to use OSGi Enterprise 4.x & JPA 2.1 Entity Listener injected via blueprint?

Tags: java, osgi, eclipselink, blueprint-osgi, jpa-2.1

We are in the OSGi world.

- [JPA 2.1 supports injectable EntityListner](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/What_is_new_in_JPA_2.1?).
- And [EclipseLink supports JPA 2.1](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/releases/2.5.php).
- But the OSGi Enterprise Spec 4.x only supports JPA 2.0.

So it seems that injectable EntityListener doesn't work in OSGi, even when EclipseLink supports them.

**Is it currently possible to define EntityListener in blueprint.xml and use them for injection?** This would allow to inject OSGi Services into an Entity Listener. (Currently we need an explicit lookup using FrameworkUtil to do the lookup.)

**Has anybody done so successfully and can share some hints, especially in regard to the used bundle (versions)?**

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the following maven dependency with org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider in the provider-Element of the persistence.xml? In the case of a JEE application server, the classloader would prefer libraries packaged with the deployed application by the ones bundled with the server itself.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```